# SSIS package for migrating data from CRM to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, dynamics-crm-2013, xrm

I am gonna start working on a CRM 2013 project which is in requirement analysis mode. We are supposed to enhance an existing xRM application as well as modify existing SSIS package which is used to transfer data from xRM to sharepoint application. As I have not got access to actual package & xRM application and as I am new to both these technologies can anybody plz help me with what R & D should I do beforehand & how can I make sure that I will be able to work on it efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use SSIS adapters from Kingsway Soft:

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-sharepoint

Here is article that describes how to use mentioned adapters - http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/03/use-kingswaysoft-and-ssis-to-create.html